# I am a novice in free radius, how can I get the user's password?

Tags: wifi, freeradius, radius

I want to do Wi-Fi authentication through radius. The password is encrypted and stored. I wrote a password-encrypted script, but the verification still fails. I checked and found that the password was not obtained. How can I obtain it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaWKW.jpg)

I tested and modified the authentication mode to ttls/pap but still can't get the password

Comment: You should paste your debug output into the question, not link it as an external image, so that it is easier for people to read and doesn't have the risk of disappearing in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing EAP, the password won't appear in the clear in the outer request.

As you have noticed you *must* use EAP-TTLS/PAP. No other (commonly in-use) method will get you the cleartext password. Configure your devices to use EAP-TTLS/PAP. It is down to the end device which EAP method they try to authenticate with. If e.g. they choose PEAP/EAP-MSCHAPv2 or EAP-TTLS/MSCHAPv2 then you won't get a cleartext password to authenticate with.

Any password checks must be made in the inner tunnel request - this will be in the virtual server in the `raddb/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel` config file, not in the outer server (`sites-enabled/default`). That is where you need to call your external script.